# Convertendo Data Para Milisegundos

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp-2

Gostaria de uma ajuda para converter essa função para o padrão Cakephp.
Ela pega a data do `datetimepiker` e transforma em milissegundos, mas procurei bastante e não achei nada parecido para o padrão [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/).

```
public function add()
{
    $this->db->set("start", $this->_formatDate($this->input->post("from")));
    $this->db->set("end", $this->_formatDate($this->input->post("to")));
}
```

Comment: Precisa o cakePhp fazer? Não pode ser uma função php ou outra biblioteca e você passa pro `$this->db` os dados?

Comment: Concordo com o @GuilhermeNascimento, qual a necessidade de ser nativo do CakePHP?